# security flaw in c code snippet?

Tags: c, security

There is supposedly something wrong (in terms of software security) with this code snippet and i cant seem to figure it out ...The function die terminates the the program after displaying the string argument.

```
void get_user(char* user)
{
  char buf[1024];
  if (strlen(user) > sizeof(buf))
    die("error: user string too long\n");
  strcpy(buf, user);
  …
}
```

-thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not counting the NUL (`\0`) terminator for the string.

```
if (strlen(user) >= sizeof(buf))
```

It's unsafe if `user` has 1024 characters (will write `0` somewhere on the stack).

Comment: While it would take a pathological implementation for `strlen(user)+1` to be able to overflow, in principle it's better to use the `>=` operator rather than addition to avoid numeric overflow issues when making tests like this.

Comment: @R.. This is interesting; can you detail about overflow issues ?

Comment: Well `strlen(user)+1` cannot overflow because the actual size of the string object includes the null termination. But suppose instead you wanted to know if objects of `size1` and `size2` will together fit in a buffer. `if (size1+size2 > available)` is not a correct test, because adding the sizes might wrap (if they're unsigned) or overflow and give UB (if they're signed). Thus, in my mind at least, conditionals of that form are a *code smell* - they indicate a potential security flaw and require further reading to determine if the code is actually safe.

Comment: @R.. Thanks for the explanation, it's quite sensible :-)

Answer (score 4):

If `strlen(user)` is equal to 1024, `strcpy` will write one byte past the end of `buf`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
if (strlen(user) > sizeof(buf))
```

this doesn't account for the null terminator when `strlen(user) == sizeof( buf )`. The check should be

```
if (strlen(user) > sizeof(buf) - 1 )
```

so that `strcpy()` can copy the null terminator at all times.

Answer (score 2):

There's an off-by-one error that could lead to a buffer overrun.  Remember that strlen gives you the number of characters in the string, *excluding* the null terminator.  The check should be:

```
if (strlen(user) + 1 > sizeof(buf))
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to do with the number of chars strcpy copies compared to the number of chars strlen returns.

Hint: [strcpy](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcpy.html), [strlen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strlen.html)

Answer (score 1):

From the strlen manpage:

> The strlen() function calculates the length of the string s, not
>   including the terminating '\0' character.

and from the strcpy manpage:

> The  strcpy() function copies the string pointed to by src, including
>   the terminating null byte ('\0'), to the buffer pointed to by dest.

There is a mismatch in the comparison of the sizes. The code checks to see whether the string length is less than the buffer, but copies string length +1 characters. If the string length (less the terminating '\0') is 1024, an overflow occurs.